# Proper way to access global helper functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently re-writing my electron app with the use of ES6 and mix to compile. Now I have my renderer file which is the main file loaded up. This then imports my app class with various methods. But what's the best way to have global access to helper functions? Ideally i'd like these functions in it's own file too. I don't really like the idea of having to import each helper. I could include the file on the renderer html, but I feel like that's not the proper way.

Files:

- renderer.js (Main file)
- App.js (my App class)
- functions.js (Helper functions)

Thanks

Comment: How are you including your "global helper functions"? posting code might help.

Comment: You *could* import the helper file as the first dependency and assign the functions to global variables as a side effect, but you *really should not*. Import the helpers individually. What don't you like about the idea of doing it the proper way?

Comment: Okay thanks. @Bergi not sure, before I began to learn ES6 I would have included the function file before the main file and therefore I could just call upon them, laziness I guess?

Also, in my renderer I include jquery, but obviously that's not accessible for App, I can use `window.$ = $` but is that the proper way? Just trying to ensure I'm doing things right before I get into any bad habits. 

Thanks

Comment: No, use a local `import $ from "jquery";`.